# c# The given path's format is not supported. UNC Path

Tags: c#, remote-server

I am trying to access and download a bak file from a remote server and keep getting the error "The given path's format is not supported."
The code I am using below:

```
string uncPath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(@"\\TSTSVR\Users\temp_databaseBackups_000kfkf000", 
  string.Format("{0}-{1}.bak", ddlDatabases.SelectedValue, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))));

//download
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(uncPath, ddlDatabases.SelectedValue + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy:hh:mm"));
```

I am getting the error at the DownloadFile line. Am I declaring the UNC path wrong? The folder is there on the server and I set access to Everyone with write permissions.

Comment: Well, what you are attempting doesn't make a lot of sense. Is the file sitting in a web server? I assume it is since you are using a WebClient object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here... `Server.MapPath` is designed to translate a website path to a physical path. It makes no sense to try to pass a UNC path to it. Are you actually trying to change a UNC path into a web path? If so you can't do it this way.

Comment: the file is sitting on a remote server at that path.

Comment: You are trying to use ```WebClient``` with Samba share. It will not work.

Comment: I just added the Server.MapPath, in trying to a couple different things. I get the same error with or without it.

Comment: You shouldn't use MapPath, and you shouldn't use WebClient, given that you have an UNC path, simply open the file directly, assuming your application is allowed to do so.

Comment: Most importantly, what do you want to do with the file? Is this a web app? Are you trying to serve it back to the user???

Comment: please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a few hints in the right direction from you all I solved the problem with the following code:

```
string uncPath = Path.Combine(@"\\TSTSVR\Users\temp_databaseBackups_000kfkf000",
  string.Format("{0}-{1}.bak", ddlDatabases.SelectedValue, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));

//download
Response.ContentType = "bak";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + ddlDatabases.SelectedValue + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy:hh:mm") + "\"");

Response.TransmitFile(uncPath);
Response.End();
```

The program will now download the file need from the remote server.

Answer (score -1):

If remote machine works under Windows control, then colon is not allowed in a path .